# Can't use function variable in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have this and I can't use the method in the class because of the error shown below.

```
class Product {
    a:number
    b:number
    get total() {
        return this.a * this.b;
    }
}

var product: Product={
    a:2,
    b:3
}
```

The error:

> Type '{ a: number; b: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Product'.
>     Property 'total' is missing in type '{ a: number; b: number; }'.

Comment: This is typescript, not javascript (changed the tag accordingly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the object can not be a *product* because the function *total* is missing. Better use the new operator.

```
const x = new Product();
x.a = 3;
x.b = 5;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Forever gratiful Mr Yonexbat

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use a constructor instead:

```
class Product {
    constructor(private a: number, private b: number) {}

    get total(): number {
        return this.a * this.b;
    }
}

let product: Product = new Product(2, 3);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. forever gratiful. Mr Jeto

Answer (score 2):

Do not confuse with TypeScript. Use the contructor like this:

```
class Product {
  constructor(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }

  total() {
    return this.a * this.b;
  }
}

var product = new Product(2, 3);
console.log(product.total());
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Forever gratiful Mr Igor Ployakov